# WebView - Embed HTML5 (CSS not working)

Tags: ios, css, xcode, html, webview

Xcode 5
In my iOS app, I have a HTML files (with css files also). I embed this files with the code below:

```
[webviewRevistas loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

This code works fine. But without "style". Seem not load the CSS file.

Note: The structure works, because if open on browser, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you still have to set the base URL like this?

```
[theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: PUT_BASE_URL_HERE];
```

The documentation states it like this:

```
 - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

**Parameters**

[string]  The content for the main page.

[baseURL] The base URL for the content.

Source: [UIWebView in Apple iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:)